# Как запретить изображению в grid-элементе растягивать высоту?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid, layout

Всем привет. Высота body 100 vh, поделил сетку, все вроде по канонам, но изображение справа получается больше (если так), появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки и изображение растягивается по высоте. А нужно чтобы ее не было и высота сетки была по высоте видимой области экрана.

```css
* {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
body {
            font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
            height: 100vh;
}
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        url('fonts/Segoe%20UI%20Semibold.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-display: swap;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
        }
        .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 10%);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 5%);
            height: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .logo {
            justify-self: start;
            grid-column: 1 / 4;
            grid-row: 1 / 5;
        }
        .logo img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .header {
            justify-self: end;
            align-self: center;
            grid-column: 10 / 11;
            grid-row: 1 / 4;
        }
        .gsi {
            background-color: #1b8183;
            grid-column: 1 / 6;
            grid-row: 10 / 18;
        }
        .pillar {
            grid-column: 6 / 11;
            grid-row: 4 / 21;
        }
        .pillar img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        /* Ссылка-текст */
        .logo-text a:active, /* активная/посещенная ссылка */
        .logo-text a:hover,  /* при наведении */
        .logo-text a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #1b8183;
        font-size: 2vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        /* Гамбургер иконка */
        .menu-btn {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-right: 50px;
        }

        .menu-btn span {
            width: 50px;
            height: 4px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: #538b99;
            border: 1px solid #538b99;
            border-radius: 10px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .menu-btn span:nth-of-type(2) {
            top: calc(40% - 5px);
        }
        .menu-btn span:nth-of-type(3) {
            top: calc(60% + 5px);
        }

        /* Меняем гамбургер иконку, когда меню открыто */
        .menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
            display: none;
        }
        .menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
        }
        .menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(-45deg);
        }

        /* Меню, которое будет появляться */
        .menu {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background: #FFEFBA;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s;
        }

        .menu.active {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }

        .menu li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .button {
            background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0);
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 15px;
            color: black;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
    <title>Сайт</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bYD24JGb/logo.png" alt="логотип"></a></div>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="gsi">Название &mdash;<br>Какой-то текст<br><input type="button" class="button" value="Написать"></div>
    <div class="pillar"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hxMnrVX/pillar.png" alt="Колонна"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Хм, смотрю в здешнем редакторе все норм, но в браузере chrome не так. Браузер что-то от себя добавляет?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С уважением

Answer (score 0):

Помогли object-fit и указание ширины и высоты img